# Удаление повторяющихся значений из списка случайных чисел

Tags: python, список, for

1. Попросите пользователя ввести количество элементов для списка.
2. Создайте список, состоящий из целых случайных чисел от 0 до 100, заданного пользователем количества.
3. Выведите этот список с помощью цикла while.
4. С помощью множеств удалите из списка все повторяющиеся значения.
5. Выведите получившийся список с помощью цикла `for`.

Первый пункт сделал и дальше в ступор как записать введенное число в список

```
while True:
    num = int(input('Введите число от 0 до 100: '))
    if num > 100:
        print('Попробуйте еще раз')
        print('Нужно ввести число меньше 100.')
    else:
        print('Вы ввели: ',num)
    break
```

Comment: п. 2 `import random`; `num = 5`; `myList = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(num)]`

Comment: `0...100` - диапазон значений случайных чисел. На их количество ограничений нет.

Comment: 2) ar = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(num)], где `num` количество объектов. Вы уже смогли его получить. Обязательно `import random`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попросите пользователя ввести количество элементов для списка.

```
n = int(input("Введите количество элементов для списка: "))
```

Создайте список, состоящий из целых случайных чисел от 0 до 100, заданного пользователем количества.

```
import random
lst = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(n)]
```

Выведите этот список с помощью цикла while.

```
i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    print(lst[i])
    i += 1
```

С помощью множеств удалите из списка все повторяющиеся значения.

```
lst2 = list(set(lst))
```

Выведите получившийся список с помощью цикла for.

```
for el in lst2:
    print(el)
```

Answer (score 1):

может быть криво и не по учебнику но работает

```
import random
try:
    num_array = list()
    num = input("Введите число от 0 до 100:")
    for i in range(int(num)):
        n = random.random() * 100
        num_array.append(int(n))
    y = 0
    while y < len(num_array):
        print(num_array)
        y+=1
except:
        print("Ты незнаешь цифры?")
```